# Open website with login credentials from terminal

Tags: command-line, login, browser

In my `.bash_aliases` file, I have some aliases in which I can open browser sessions:

```
alias thisismyalias='xdg-open https://somesite/login'
```

The problem however is that it doesn't remember my credentials and I don't have a "remember me" option. Appearantly, I could trick my browser into thinking I filled in the credentials by using following command:

```
xdg-open https://user:password@somesite/login
```

but this results in a popup box with following content:

```
You are about to log in to the site “somesite” with the username “user”, 
but the website does not require authentication. 
This may be an attempt to trick you. 
Is “somesite” the site you want to visit?
```

I confirm that this is indeed the site I want to visit, but I my credentials aren't filled in. Is there any way to pass my credentials to my browser?